# Prometheus work with blackbox exporter to fetch sample data

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

We are using prometheus operator which works as expected, We want now to add the blackbox exporter

I've installed in the same namespace like Prometheus with https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-blackbox-exporter

Now I've update the config (values.yaml)and install the chart with the update new values like:

```
 helm upgrade --install bbe stable/prometheus-blackbox-exporter -f values.yaml -n po
```

*Took the defaults...*

```
  targets:
    - name: example                    # Human readable URL that will appear in Prometheus / AlertManager
      url: http://example.com/healthz  # The URL that blackbox will scrape
      labels: {}                       # List of labels for ServiceMonitor. Overrides value set in `defaults`
      interval: 60s                    # Scraping interval. Overrides value set in `defaults`
      scrapeTimeout: 60s               # Scrape timeout. Overrides value set in `defaults`
      module: http_2xx                 # Module used for scraping. Overrides value set in `defaults`
```

https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-blackbox-exporter/values.yaml#L137

I've configure the target to use `blackbox exporter` like following

https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-operator/values.yaml#L1872

```
additionalScrapeConfigs:
  - job_name: 'blackbox'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9115']
```

Get svc to the namespace returns the follwing:

```
bbe-prometheus-blackbox-exporter    ClusterIP  100.26.213.43 9115/TCP       19h
```

if I change the config to use the `svc` like following

```
additionalScrapeConfigs:
  - job_name: 'blackbox'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['bbe-prometheus-blackbox-exporter:9115']
```

I see that it up on the target,

[image]

However, still we doesn't see any of the `example` metric in Prometheus UI, Any idea what could be missing here? should I search of other metric property and not `example`?

[image]

btw, I run `port-forward` for blackbox, and use `http://localhost:9115/metrics` and **I dont see** the `example` entry there (see many others which come by default) , any idea what could be wrong? how should I search for it?

In addition, if I take one entry from the blackbox exporter properties which I got when calling to `http://localhost:9115/metric` like `go_info` and run execute I see the following `go_info{instance="bbe-prometheus-blackbox-exporter:9115", job="blackbox", version="go1.13.4"}` which I guess prometheus is connect to blackbox exporter, however I dont see the metric `example` which I configure in blackbox exporter

**update**

I've use the `additionalScrapeConfig` property according to the comments of @FL3SH and I see that in the target. my question is for instance how should I query one of the entries (in Prometheus ui) ,lets say I want to know if `cncf` endpoint is up and running.

[image]

Comment: Check with port-forward if blackbox exporter exposes `example` metrics. I also recommend checking [this](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/256#issuecomment-470600179) configuration example.

Comment: @FL3SH - thanks, I run port-forward for blackbox,  and use `http://localhost:9115/metrics` and I dont see the `example` entry there (see many others which come by default) , any idea what could be wrong? how should I search for it? or did I configure it incorrect ? as I didnt do anything special just use the defalut of the helm chart ...

Comment: @FL3SH  If I take one entry from the blackbox exporter properties which I got when calling to `http://localhost:9115/metric`   like `go_info` and run execute I see the following `go_info{instance="bbe-prometheus-blackbox-exporter:9115", job="blackbox", version="go1.13.4"}` which I guess prometheus is connect to blackbox exporter, however I dont see the metric `example` which I configure in blackbox exporter

Comment: Did you follow linked configuration?

Comment: @FL3SH - thanks a lot, I use the `## Monitor external services` and I see it up in the target . This is a big progress I've some additional question two questions.  1. why it doesnt works with the configuration of the blackbox exporter values.yaml . 2 . there is two targets `cncf & //kubernetespodcast.com` in case I want to query one of the entry in prometheus UI, how should I do it, lets say I want to know just if the cncf target is up? should I add some label to it, if yes how? is there is any example?

Comment: @FL3SH. - I try many queries in the UI and I didnt get anything, i'll update my question with the screen shot to make more realistic

Comment: @FL3SH - please see my update

Comment: [dhyanio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14008969) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69516115) saying "Yes, there is an article for complete Blackbox understanding. [https://kubefront.com/linux/how-to-install-and-configure-blackbox-exporter-for-prometheus](https://kubefront.com/linux/how-to-install-and-configure-blackbox-exporter-for-prometheus)"